# In Java how to remove try catch block inside a Constructor for I/O code

Tags: java, exception, constructor, try-catch

In Java How can I write I/O code that must be in try catch block inside a Constructor without try-catch in the costructor? Like for a method we can pass the exception to the caller of the method by writing throws in method defination and we can remove try-catch. how we can remove try-catch in a constructor for the I/O code. Thats question asked by a interviewer to me. i said it cant be done and i really dont have an idea. Guys what you think. Please suggest??

Comment: You do it in the same exact way that you do for a method - by declaring the checked exception in the `throws` part of the declaration.

Comment: Err. create a separate `initialize()` method and call it on your newly created object?

Comment: Oh man, it sounds like you were over thinking the interview question.

Answer (score 8):

Use this:

```
public class Foo
{
   public Foo() throws IOException
   {
       doSomeIO();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Same way you do to the methods. Just declerare a throws statement.

Trying this would be easier than typing this long question here though. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `throws` clause also to a constructor, similarly to any other method.